# Localhost rendering different

Tags: html, css, webserver, localhost, server

I am moving my site over to a local WAMP server to make testing easier instead of uploading files all the time to my live site.  However, my code loads differently visually in the browser on localhost than it does on the live site.  The live site everything loads fine and in the proper place.  In my localhost, things are out of place.  Any ideas as to what this is?  Is this CSS rendering differently between servers?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you have some `404`. Double check the `.net` panel in your js console and look at the file paths

Comment: You are probably just missing files, such as CSS and Javascript files. Check your console for more info.

Comment: No files are missing, I push from Dreamweaver the exact same files.  It is a exact copy of the same files

Comment: That still doesn't give us enough to go on. Have you checked your browser's debug tools as suggested to see if everything loads? While you're at it, check what other differences there may be between both servers in terms of HTTP headers being sent. Finally: what exactly is different? As given this is really vague.

Comment: if by Headers you mean HTTP vs HTTPS then both are sending via HTTP.  As for the difference, this is the live server:  http://i1131.photobucket.com/albums/m554/seafight4us/webhost_zpsodmhc1tl.png  and this is the locally hosted WAMP server: http://i1131.photobucket.com/albums/m554/seafight4us/localhost_zps0by1mdhh.png  Ignore the broken images in both, that is on purpose.  In the console it is showing that the -moz- webkit is being ignored even though im using firefox as well as some Jquery being disiked, however, the same jquery runs fine from the live server, just not the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

$config['base_url'] = "http://sample.com"; // For live
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/sample.com"; // to run in local

So Use the common declaration for URL base_url()

Answer (score 0):

I was an idiot and didnt do enough tracking I had conflicting php includes that the live server handled fine but my local server didnt handle well.  Problem solved.  Thank you all.